# Is this example tcp socket programming sequence of events safe?

Tags: ruby, sockets, asynchronous, go

I plan on having two services.

1. HTTP REST service written in Ruby
2. JSON RPC service written in Go

The Ruby service will open a TCP socket connection to a Go JSON RPC service. It'll do this for each incoming HTTP request it receives. It will send some data over the socket to the Go service and that service will subsequently send back the corresponding data back down the socket.

### Go code

The Go service go would look something like this (simplified):

```
srv := new(service.App) // this would expose a Process method

rpc.Register(srv)

listener, err := net.Listen("tcp", ":8080")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}

for {
    conn, err := listener.Accept()
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    go jsonrpc.ServeConn(conn)
}
```

Notice we serve the incoming connection using a goroutine, so we can handle requests concurrently.

### Ruby code

Below is a simple snippet of Ruby code that demonstrates (in theory) the way I would send data to the Go service:

```
require "socket"
require "json"

socket = TCPSocket.new "localhost", "8080"

b = {
  :method => "App.Process",
  :params => [{ :Config => JSON.generate({ :foo => :bar }) }],
  :id     => "0"
}

socket.write(JSON.dump(b))

response = JSON.load socket.readline
```

My concern is: **will this be a safe sequence of events?**

I'm not asking if this will be 'thread safe', because i'm not worried about manipulating shared memory across the go routines. I'm more concerned around whether my Ruby HTTP service will get back the data it's expecting?

If I have two parallel requests coming into my HTTP Service (or maybe the Ruby app is hosted behind a load balancer and so different *instances* of the HTTP service is handling multiple requests), then I could have instance A send the message Foo to the Go service; while instance B sends the message Bar.

The business logic inside the Go service will return different responses depending on its input so I want to be sure that Ruby instance A gets back the correct response for Foo, and B gets back the correct response for Bar.

I assume a socket connection is more like a queue in that if instance A makes a request to the Go service first and *then* B does, but B is quicker responding for whatever reason, then the Go service will write the response for B to the socket and instance A of the Ruby app will end up reading in the wrong socket data (this is obviously just one possible *scenario* considering that I could get *lucky* and have instance B read the socket data before instance A does).

### Solutions?

I'm not sure if there is *simple* solution to this problem. Unless I don't use a TCP socket or RPC and instead rely on standard HTTP in the Go service. But I wanted the performance and less overhead of TCP.

I'm worried the design could get more complicated by maybe having to implement an external queue as a way of synchronising the responses with the Ruby service.

It maybe because the nature of my Ruby service is fundamentally synchronous (HTTP response/request) that I have no option but to switch to HTTP for the Go service.

But wanted to double check with the community first just in case I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is safe if you create a new connection every time.

That said there are latent issues with your approach:

1. TCP connections are rather expensive to establish, so you probably want to re-use connections with a connection pool
2. If you make too many simultaneous requests you will exhaust ports/open file descriptors which will cause your program to crash
3. You don't have any timeouts in place, so it's possible to end up with orphaned TCP connections which never complete (either because of something bad on the Go side, or network problems)

I think you'd be better off using HTTP (despite the overhead) since libraries are already written to cope with these problems. HTTP is also much more debuggable since you can just curl an endpoint to test it.

Personally I'd probably go with [gRPC](http://www.grpc.io/).

Comment: Thanks @caleb. I'm going to look at gRPC (as you suggested) which looks to let me take advantage of HTTP/2 and let's me easily define services and generate client/server code for multiple languages including Ruby and Go.